# Pandas, python: Count unique name-method occurrences each 5 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've been given a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
             datetime                               name  mtd  code
0 2017-09-07 00:00:08                        profile/log  GET  300
1 2017-09-07 00:00:17                        profile/log  PUT  300
3 2017-09-07 00:00:19                             unknown PUT  200
4 2017-09-07 00:00:21                   extras/dashboard  GET  300
5 2017-09-07 00:00:23                       extras/stats  GET  300
6 2017-09-07 00:00:26                 extras/dashboard    GET  300
7 2017-09-07 00:00:29         extras/authz-profile/check  GET  200
8 2017-09-07 00:00:34                              about  PUT  300
9 2017-09-07 00:00:36                         extras/fav  GET  304
2 2017-09-07 00:00:44                       extras/store  GET  200
```

What I want to do is:

- to count number of occurrences for each name-mtd pair **where response code starts with 3** *for each 5 second interval starting from `2017-09-07 00:00:10` to `2017-09-07 00:00:40`*

The desirable output is:

```
     datetime_start     pair                      3??_count
2017-09-07 00:00:10     profile/log - GET         2
2017-09-07 00:00:15     -                         0
2017-09-07 00:00:20     extras/dashboard - GET    1
2017-09-07 00:00:20     extras/stats - GET        1
2017-09-07 00:00:25     extras/dashboard - GET    1
2017-09-07 00:00:30     about - PUT               1
2017-09-07 00:00:35     extras/fav - GET          1
2017-09-07 00:00:40     -                         0
```

How am I to do that with **pandas**?

I have written a piece of code that creates time periods as shown in the `desirable output` table, but don't know how to count a 3?? name-mtd pair for each 5-second period. I would highly appreciate any help!

```
data['datetime_start'] = pd.date_range(start="2017-09-07 00:00:10", end="2017-09-07 00:00:40", freq="5S")
```

Comment: Tricky one! Sounds like an exam question or something. Could you share the groupby code that you've already tried and then someone can build from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the start_date column

```
df['start_date']= df[' datetime'].apply(lambda dt: datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour,dt.minute ,5*(dt.second//5)))
```

then you can aggregate

```
df.groupby(['start_date','name','mtd']).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to approach this

create a column that combines  name-mtd as below

```
df['pair'] = df['name']+' - '+df['mtd']
```

then use PeriodIndex to specify the period to group the column datatime on as shown below

```
res = df.groupby([pd.PeriodIndex(df.datetime.dt.round('5s'),freq='5S'),
                'pair'])['pair'].count()
```

The output will be

```
datetime             pair                            
2017-09-07 00:00:10  profile/log - GET                   1
2017-09-07 00:00:15  profile/log - PUT                   1
2017-09-07 00:00:20  extras/dashboard - GET              1
                     unknown - PUT                       1
2017-09-07 00:00:25  extras/dashboard - GET              1
                     extras/stats - GET                  1
2017-09-07 00:00:30  extras/authz-profile/check - GET    1
2017-09-07 00:00:35  about - PUT                         1
                     extras/fav - GET                    1
2017-09-07 00:00:45  extras/store - GET                  1
Name: pair, dtype: int64
```